# Try-catch to check existence of nested elements: is it good php?

Tags: php

Consider an array in the form:

```
$parent = [
  'children' => [
    'visible' => true,
    'items' => ['petro', 'johano', 'karlo']
  ]
];
```

I need to check whether `$parent['children']['items']` has some elements or not.

I know it could be done as follows:

```
function has_children($parent) {
  if (!isset($parent['children'])) return false;
  if (!isset($parent['children']['items'])) return false;
  if (!is_array($parent['children']['items'])) return false;
  if (count($parent['children']['items']) == 0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

But I would prefer to do that the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) way, i.e. something like:

```
function has_children($parent) {
  try {
    $parent['children']['items'][0];
    return true;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Is this safe and good practice in php, or does it have some drawbacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the array is expected to have numeric indexes starting with zero, then you could just use:

```
function has_children($parent) {
  return isset($parent['children']['items'][0]);
}
```

`isset` doesn't really "dereference" the array, so there's no need to check the existence of `$parent['children']` before checking the existence of `$parent['children']['items']`, and so on.

---

Whether it's a good idea to attempt to access an element and catch an exception — it depends, but most probably no, it's not a good idea. 
Exceptions introduce an additional performance overhead, and they *semantically* indicate an *exceptional situation,* which it isn't if you are just checking emptiness.

Comment: I should have been checking the manual for `isset` a little bit deeper, a similar case was described in the first example. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `empty()` function which show is array empty or not.
try catch is not recommended

use this code:

```
if (!empty($parent['children'])){
    if (!empty($parent['children'])){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: This is the same as `return !empty($parent['children'])) && !empty($parent['children'])`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running that code? Besides the syntax errors, it will not work that way: as you can see at https://3v4l.org/dqGn8, accessing an invalid array key only generates a notice, not an exception. So there is nothing that could get caught

Comment: My bad, I thought I couldn't fail putting down a few lines of code. I've fixed it now.